# How to Keep html table dimension same using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have table with images with 4 cols and 2 rows. I shuffle the table using this code:

```
function sortTable() {
  //get the parent table for convenience
  let table = document.getElementById("imgTable");

  //1. get all rows
  let rowsCollection = table.querySelectorAll("td");

  //2. convert to array
  let rows = Array.from(rowsCollection)
    

  //3. shuffle
  shuffleArray(rows);

  //4. add back to the DOM
  for (const row of rows) {
    table.appendChild(row);
  }
}


function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
}
```

But after shuffle, everything gets into 1 row and 8 cols. How do i keep the dimension same?

[Here is the Demo of what is happening](http://g.recordit.co/rXmyrDntuK.gif)

Comment: You're shuffling the `td` elements, and then appending them directly on `table` element, you've to distribute the `td`s to the `tr` elements.

Comment: ```tr``` will shuffle the two rows and both are rows are identical, so it wont actually randomize anything. Thats why i used ```td```to shuffle all the table data values @Teemu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said in the comment, you're appending the shuffled cells directly to the table element. That's not a permitted parent element for `td` elements. Instead, distribute the shuffled cells back to the original rows.

```js
function sortTable() {
  //get the parent table for convenience
  let table = document.getElementById("imgTable");

  //1. get all rows
  let cellCollection = table.querySelectorAll("td");

  //2. convert to array
  let cells = Array.from(cellCollection)


  //3. shuffle
  shuffleArray(cells);

  //4. add back to the DOM
  const rows = table.rows,
    len = rows.length;
  let index = 0;
  for (const cell of cells) {
    const row = rows[index++ % len];
    row.appendChild(cell);
  }
}


function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
}
sortTable();
```

```html
<table id="imgTable">
  <tr>
    <td>R1C1</td>
    <td>R1C2</td>
    <td>R1C3</td>
    <td>R1C4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R2C1</td>
    <td>R2C2</td>
    <td>R2C3</td>
    <td>R2C4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've also changed some variable names to better describe the content.

Answer (score 2):

I think you select wrong selector it should be `tr`

```js
function sortTable() {
  //get the parent table for convenience
  let table = document.getElementById("imgTable");

  //1. get all rows
  let rowsCollection = table.querySelectorAll("tr");

  //2. convert to array
  let rows = Array.from(rowsCollection)


  //3. shuffle
  shuffleArray(rows);

  //4. add back to the DOM
  for (const row of rows) {
    table.appendChild(row);
  }
}


function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
}

const shuffle = document.getElementById('shuffle');
shuffle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sortTable()
});
```

```html
<button id="shuffle">shuffle</button>

<table id="imgTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ```tr``` will shuffle the two rows and both are rows are identical, so it wont actually randomize anything. Thats why i used ```td``` to shuffle all the table data values

Comment: as you can see in your code snippet, after the shuffle the rows are still same 2 2 2 2 or 1 1 1 1 1. I am trying to get something like 2 3 1 2, 1 2 3 3 , 2 1 3 1 etc